# Why to use .remove(elem) when there is .discard(elem) in python?

Tags: python

`.discard(x)`: This operation removes element from the set.
If element does not exist, it does not raise a KeyError.

`.remove(x)`: This operation removes element from the set.
If element does not exist, it raises a KeyError.

So my question is, where is the reason to use `remove(x)` function since it can cause problem to our program by erasing an error. I feel like it is useless function since `discard(x)` does the exact same thing without causing any unpredictable behavior to our program.

Comment: sometimes you want to know about errors and act accordingly...

Comment: Wouldn't you **want** to get an error if you are trying to remove and element that doesn't exist? I mean... you thought it was there - but it's not - I would think this is an error that you would want to know about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes errors are useful. You can use `try: except:` to catch these errors, and do different things depending on whether that piece of code caused an error. For example:

```
try:
    list.remove(elem)
    print("Item removed!")
except KeyError as e:
    print("Sorry, that item was not in the set. More information: %s".format(str(e)))
```

Comment: ok, I got the concept. Thank you very much!!!